# UIView height not properly scaling with image across devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, scaling

I am working on an app that uses a picker to rotate through basic bars of colors. These bars are supposed to match the height and be at specific locations on the width of the background image. The image is a scalable vector and set to Aspect Fit. The image also includes some white space, so the bars cannot simply be set to the exact same height as the image. To create the bars I created a simple rectangular `UIView` and set the background color as needed. The picker method is as follows:

```
imageSize = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(myImage.image!.size, myImage.frame)

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let imageHeight = self.imageSize.height
    let imageWidth = self.imageSize.width

    let barWidth = imageWidth * 0.055

    var frame: CGRect

    switch component {
    case 1: // First component needs to match tan portions height
        let barHeight = imageHeight * 0.85

        frame = CGRect(x: -barWidth/2, y: -barHeight/2, width: barWidth, height: barHeight)
        break
    case 3, 4, 5: // another part of image has different height
        let barHeight = imageHeight * 0.64

        frame = CGRect(x: -barWidth/2, y: -barHeight/2, width: barWidth, height: barHeight)
        break
    default: // return empty views for spacers
        return UIView()
    }


    let stripe = UIView(frame: frame)
    stripe.backgroundColor = getColor(component, row: row)
    return stripe

}
```

To calculate the `imageHeight` I have used multiple methods, all without success. I have directly used the `myImage.image.size.height` as well as using `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`. The image is spanning the width of the device. Here are some screenshots of a sliver of the image:

on 6S:

[image: 6S]
[image: 6S Band Sizes]

on 6S Plus:

[image: 6S Plus]
on 5S:

[image: 5S]

As you can see the bar does not properly align with light tan portion of the background image, furthermore the horizontal location is off as well. I had thought using percentages would maintain proper alignment through scaling but I guess I was wrong.

Has anyone had experience with this that may be able to see what I've done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure you should be using `let barHeight = imageHeight * 0.85` if you want it to equal the image height. You should look into programmatically using size classes.

Comment: why don't you use autolayouts? and where did you get the 0.85 calculation?
If you want to do it like this, do `let barHeight = screenHeight * 0.85`

Comment: @RyanCollins I don't want it to exactly equal the image height. the image has some white space that I don't need to match to.

Comment: You would need to post more code than the above so the community can see exactly how it works to get a better answer.

Comment: @NikitaP These views are within a picker and done programatically. The .85 of the IMAGE is simply what matched the proper size on the 6S. I don't understand your logic on using the screen size. I was the bar to be scaled to the image specifically

Comment: @RyanCollins Sure, Although I can't think of any besides the calculation of the imageheight. which I've added

Comment: You never know with Cocoa. Just like buttons need a method to update their labels rather than setting the text to a string directly.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted but I will reformat the question with the entirety of the picker function to improve clarity when I get home

Comment: Original Question has been updated

Comment: Can people please comment as to why they are down voting? As this seems to be a valid question and it hurts my chances of getting it answered 

Answer (score 0):

I got my scaling to work by using a percentage of the width as a height for my bars. This works only because the image is set to Aspect Fit and is the same width as the screen.

This is an ugly solution and only valid for a specific set of applications. It seems as though the image size is not reliable to compare to or does not return the proper size in relation to different devices. I Haven't figured out why my original logic did not work.